# Extend SSAS for MSBuild like you can for SSIS

Tags: azure-devops, ssas, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, automated-deploy

Hey so I figured out how to do automated deployment in Hosted Builds for VSTS for SSIS. I used the article in this link (https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/) with a lot of research and trial and error to make it work for modern settings aka VS17, SQL16, and DotNet 4.6.1.

Anyways I was to do the exact same kind of process now for SSAS. I do not want to use Devenv.exe for this task. Reason being Hosted VSTS builds do not have licenses associated with their Visual Studio thus forcing the use of MSBuild instead. Looking for articles and guides that do not use Devenv.exe.

Ideal situation would be Msbuild extension like I did for SSIS that I can point it at the solution or the .dwproj file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building SSAS project through MSBuild directly is not supported, check this user voice: [Support SSAS / SSIS / SSRS in Msbuild](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/11536152-support-ssas-ssis-ssrs-in-msbuild).

You can setup a private build agent: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows), then do build/release by using this agent.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a code base or github project link hopefully from someone who has done their own MSBuild customization. I know Microsoft currently doesn't support it and I have a ticket open with them to ask alternatives. I was just hoping someone out there who is a MSBuild expert would see this and share.

Comment: The MSBuild customization uses devenv.exe too: http://www.dimodelo.com/blog/2014/automate-build-and-deployment-of-ssas-cubes-using-msbuild/